React Native: Fata Error - AmplifyRTNCore/AmplifyRTNCore.modulemap not found
I am trying to build a react native application and get it ready for submission through apple developer portal. When I try to build it in X-code, I get the following error:
/Users/omarjandali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grubber-ayrnljwcgsxfhigtvjiavybjeacs/Build/
Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Grubber/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Grubber.build/
Release-iphoneos/Grubber.build/DerivedSources/Grubber_vers.c 
module map file '/Users/omarjandali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
Grubber-ayrnljwcgsxfhigtvjiavybjeacs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/
ArchiveIntermediates/Grubber/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/
AmplifyRTNCore/AmplifyRTNCore.modulemap' not found

I did integrate AWS amplify into my proejct and it works on my local machine and simulator but when i try to build the project it fails the build. Not sure why it is crashing.
Here is my pod file:
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Grubber' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'GrubberTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
  end
end



I did run pod install and it runns the install command perfectly with no issues and it completes the install process. I can add additional information if needed.
----------- UPDATE --------------------
I tried to go in and switch the Architectures to arm64 like I read and I ran into a different error:

I switched to arm64

This is the build error I gett when running after chagnes:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/omarjandali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grubber-ayrnljwcgsxfhigtvjiavybjeacs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Grubber/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Grubber.build/Release-iphoneos/Grubber.build/Script-EBD8442A6D35B47C0D374CB4.sh (in target 'Grubber' from project 'Grubber')
    cd /Users/omarjandali/GrubberInc/Grubber/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/omarjandali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grubber-ayrnljwcgsxfhigtvjiavybjeacs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Grubber/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Grubber.build/Release-iphoneos/Grubber.build/Script-EBD8442A6D35B47C0D374CB4.sh

mkdir -p /Users/omarjandali/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grubber-ayrnljwcgsxfhigtvjiavybjeacs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Grubber/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Grubber.app/Frameworks
/Users/omarjandali/GrubberInc/Grubber/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Grubber/Pods-Grubber-frameworks.sh: line 42: source: unbound variable
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

